# I need to re-type query every time I reopen SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a saved query I like to use but for some reason - every time I reopen SQL the query does not work and says

"Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.vwCreemes_PNT_DieSortStorage_Transactions'.

```
select dbo.vwCreemes_PNT_DieSortStorage_Transactions.*,dbo.vwADFab_AllLinkedWafer.TrackInfo From dbo.vwCreemes_PNT_DieSortStorage_Transactions
LEFT JOIN dbo.vwADFab_AllLinkedWafer
    ON dbo.vwCreemes_PNT_DieSortStorage_Transactions.LotID = dbo.vwADFab_AllLinkedWafer.WaferID
    ORDER BY dbo.vwCreemes_PNT_DieSortStorage_Transactions.TransactionTime desc
```

However - when I type the exact same thing in another new query - it works.

Both these tables exist within the same Server. I am connected to that server everytime

Comment: Tables (or views) don't exist within a "server". They exist within a database in a server instance. Don't know exactly what "reopen SQL" means but it seems the current database is not set to the one you need. I suggest you simply add the appropriate "USE <your db name here>;" as the first statement in your script.

Comment: Tyy to add as a very first line: `USE <yourDatabaseName>` in SSMS.

Comment: Copy the statement to a text-only file to see and erase possible invisible Unicode characters.

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.